# is it possible to save a menu as css

Tags: html, css, menu

I have created a css only menu for ebay.

I have about 300 listings so if I want to change a link or edit the menu I have to go through each listing. Obviously this is very time consuming. My question is this, can i save the menu on a separate page so I can update when I like which will update all the ebay listings?

i cannot use php or javascript as ebay wont let me

Answer (score 0):

For "your" ebay? Don't know what that's supposed to mean...

Anyways, sounds like time for our old friend php!

Put the menu code in a file called `menu.php`, make the files that include the menu also php files, and replace the menu code in them with:

`<?php
    require('menu.php');`
?>

Does this in each file where the menu is displayed.

This will simply put the code in there for you, getting it from menu.php. So, in the future you will only have to modify menu.php, and the changes will appear everywhere.

Comment: Hi its just my ebay account. problem is ebay wont let you use php or javascript

Comment: Oh, I see - well if ebay doesn't allow you to do any coding, there is nothing you can do.

Comment: tell a lie sorry i can use php.

Comment: So then, that should save you some time

Comment: yea but i cannot get it working i replaced the menu with <?php require('menu.php'); ?> and it didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of software applications available for making it easier to manage multiple eBay listings. Some of these must let you create a template once and then apply it to all of your auctions. Then you can keep your existing CSS in the template.